# Plotting multiple polygons with a for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, polygon

I am extracting polygons from a .shp file in a for loop in python and I want to plot all of them in the same image.

I found below code online for plotting multiple polygon in the same image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coord = [[1,1], [2,1], [2,2], [1,2], [0.5,1.5],[1,1]] 
coord2 = [[2,1], [3,5], [5,5], [6,2], [0.5,1.5],[2,1]] 

xs, ys = zip(*coord) 
xi, yi = zip(*coord2)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xs,ys)
plt.plot(xi,yi) 
plt.show()
```

However, I have hundreds of polygon, so I don't want to manually all insert them there. I can add all the polygons to a list, but I don't know how to plot all the polygons from that list in the same image.

Comment: Looks like you can basically use the code in your example. Add the for loop around the coord/xs,ys,plt.plot commands and call plt.figure and plt.show only once.

Comment: @allo Hey, I tried this, but it gives me one good figure and one empty one. My code shows like this, what am I doing wrong?

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coordlist = list()

coord = [[1,1], [2,1], [2,2], [1,2], [0.5,1.5],[1,1]] 
coord2 = [[2,1], [3,5], [5,5], [6,2], [0.5,1.5],[2,1]] 

coordlist.append(coord)
coordlist.append(coord2)

for i in coordlist:
    xs, ys = zip(*i) 
    plt.plot(xs,ys)


plt.figure()
plt.show()`